# Which file system sort order is fastest in Windows 10 for large libraries?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, sorting

Which file system sort order is fastest to load in Windows 10 for large libraries?
My intuition always told me that sorting by date modified was the fastest one to load up.

Comment: My guess would be `Name`, as it's the default when you create a new folder, drop some files nto it, and view it for thefirst time; or when you delete the sort specificaation from a saved view and then open the folder. Though it wouldn't be the most efficient in low-level code, it was probably given the most optimization attention by delopers. Indexing probably plays a role as well, and I imagine `Name` is optimized there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to choose filesystem sort order – only the order that Explorer will *display* files in. And in most cases, it can only apply the sort order *after* it has already loaded all of the metadata it needs (it can't ask the filesystem to give it a pre-sorted list of files – it gets a list of files first, loads their metadata later, though possibly in parallel).

So there shouldn't be much of a difference as long as your sort field is part of the basic filesystem metadata (i.e. not file-embedded metadata like Exif or ID3 tags; *that* is certainly going to be slower).

In the NTFS filesystem, directories are stored as B+trees rather than simple lists of files, so the filesystem enforces a specific order – all names within a directory are sorted alphabetically, regardless of when they were added or changed.

(In the FAT filesystem, each directory is indeed a simple list, but its order isn't "last modification", it's closer to file *creation* time... though not exactly, as files moved from one directory to another could be placed at the end despite being older, and similarly new files could be placed in a unused hole in the middle rather than always going at the end.)

Comment: note that files in NTFS are only sorted in the US English locale without any special symbols, otherwise it's an almost sorted list

Comment: I think internally it's sorted by Unicode codepoint, which isn't really "alphabetical sort" for other languages, but has a well-defined order nevertheless.